# What is the execution environment where `command [arguments]` in `exec command [arguments]` runs?

Tags: bash, exec

From bash manual

> **exec**
>
> ```
> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new
>   process. If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the
>   beginning of the zeroth argument passed to command. This is what the
>   login program does. **The -c option causes command to be executed with
>   an empty environment**.

Without `-c` option, what is the execution environment where `command [arguments]` runs?

- Is it the same as the execution environment in the original shell process before running `exec command [arguments]`?
- The execution environment in the original shell process contains not only environment variables but also all the shell variables including non-environment ones. Does the execution environment where `command` in `exec command` runs also include the non-environment variables in the original shell process?

Can you give some examples to show that?

Comment: You're conflating two things: *execution environment* and *environment variables*. The `-c` option to Bash `exec` clears all environment variables -- try e.g. `bash -c 'exec env'` and `bash -c 'exec -c env'`. As to the [execution environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12), it is the same at the point of invocation of the command.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @glennjackman: Done, but since I seem to be physically unable to avoid being verbose (I'm not kidding, and I don't mean that as a joke!), it grew into a wall of text. If you care, you (or somebody else) could write a more concise summary, since I believe very few will bother to read my long-winded answer.

Comment: The execution environment does not contain any non-environment variables, by definition. Therefore, preserving the execution environment could not preserve any non-environment variable.

Comment: @sorontar The execution environment does contain any non-environment variables. "The shell has an execution environment, which consists of the following: ... shell parameters that are set by variable assignment or with set or inherited from the shell’s parent in the environment"  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html

Comment: And those "shell parameters" (in shell parlance) are the only "environment variables" (in your words). There are no other **variables**. The other elements are **not** variables, are: open files, cwd, umask, traps, functions, options, aliases, pid's. Nothing of that is an "environment variable".

Comment: @sorontar  those "shell parameters" include those variables not exported to the environment.

Comment: No, they don't. Variables not exported cease to exist in any other new shell (sub-shells are a very different issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are conflating two different things: [execution environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) and [environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08).

Environment variables are strings of form `name=value`, and are used as a form of configuration for the commands and processes. For example, `PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories where executable commands are looked for, when only the file name of the command is supplied; `LANG` and various variables starting with `LC_` control the locale, and so on.

Execution environment includes all the shell features that affect how commands might be run. It includes environment variables, of course, but also things like the working directory, file creation mask (`umask`), shell functions and aliases defined, and so on.

At the point of execution -- the moment when the shell starts executing the command --, the execution environment is almost exactly the same in all cases, with or without `exec`. With `exec`, the shell `EXIT` trap is triggered (because the shell is essentially exiting, when replaced by another process). With `exec -c`, the environment variables are cleared.

The `-c` flag to Bash `exec` only clears the environment variables. If you run

```
bash -c `exec env`
```

you start a new Bash shell, which is then replaced by the `env` command; which, when no other parameters are specified, just outputs all environment variables. However, if you add the `-c` flag to `exec`, i.e.

```
bash -c `exec -c env`
```

it prints nothing, and that is because `env` is run with no environment variables (or, in other words, an empty environment).

(If you run just `exec env` in a terminal, the shell running in the terminal will be replaced by the `env` command, and when it exits, the terminal will close. It'll probably happen too fast for you to see. This is why I explicitly run it under Bash, as that way, it's that sub-Bash that gets replaced, and not the shell your terminal is using.)

I have not seen the `-c` option used in real life scripts, as usually `env -i` is used instead. For example:

```
bash -c `exec env -i PATH=$PATH env`
```

With parameters, the `env` command is used to run a command with modified environment variables; the `-i` option is used to start from scratch; i.e. clear all existing environment variables. Because the shell parses the entire command (line) before executing it, you can use `env -i VAR=$VAR OTHER=$OTHER` to keep specific environment variables -- by telling `env` to define them with the old values they had when the shell parsed the command line. In the above, the final `env` just prints out the resulting environment variables, but it could be any other command.

Comment: Thanks. In the execution environment where `command` in `exec command` runs, are the aspects other than environment variables   the same as those in the execution environment in the original shell process?

Comment: @Tim: At the point of execution, everything. (Well, unless you consider it a difference that with `exec`, the `EXIT` trap is triggered before the command is run.)

Comment: @Tim: `exec` really is that simple. See, for example, the [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) POSIX documentation. It is very often used when the shell script is used to modify environment variables, maybe check parameters or environment variables, and then replace itself with the proper application. In many Linux distributions, many applications -- even Firefox -- use such scripts to launch the application proper. It makes it simpler to use the same application in different distributions, as only small changes are needed in the script part.

Comment: @Tim: If you do not use `exec` in those cases, the shell will remain in memory, doing nothing, for as long as the application runs. (While it does not waste much CPU, it does waste resources, a bit of memory at least.) As soon as the application exits, the script will exit too. So, there really is no need for having the shell remain in memory; `exec` is the way to avoid that.

Comment: the execution environment in the original shell process contains not only environment variables but also all the shell variables including non-environment ones. Does  the execution environment where `command` in `exec command` runs also include the non-environment  variables in the original shell process?

Comment: @Tim Shell variables are lost when a new shell starts: `a=42; echo "one=$a";bash -c 'echo "t22=$a"'` will print `one=42 t22= `. the value of a shell variable `$a` is lost. In an exec, that is also true.

Comment: @sorontar can you show that 'In an exec, that is also true.'

Comment: This: `a=42; echo "one=$a";bash -c 'echo "t22=$a"'; bash -c 'exec echo "t33=$a"'` And stop the repetition.

Comment: I'm confused by the backticks in your examples, e.g. `bash -c [bt]exec env[bt]` (where [bt] is a backtick, can't figure out how to format that in a comment).  Shouldn't it be `bash -c 'exec env'` (which I tried and does what I expect)